# Bcftools 1.16 able to add F_MISSING tag?

Tags: bcftools

I tried adding the F_MISSING tag using bcftools 1.16. When I run this command:

```
bcftools +fill-tags input.vcf.gz -- -t 'F_MISSING' | bcftools view -i 'INFO/F_MISSING<0.25' -Oz -o output.vcf.gz
```

I get the following error:

```
Error parsing "--tags F_MISSING": the tag "F_MISSING" is not supported
```

This command runs fine using bcftools 1.15. However, version 1.15 gives complications with other packages I use in my snakefile. Do you maybe know alternatives for how to add F_MISSING using bcftls 1.16 (if possible)?

When I type `bcftools +fill-tags --version`:

bcftools 1.9 using htslib 1.9

plugin at 1.9 using htslib 1.9

##SOLUTION##

Indeed the issue was that I was not installing the most recent version of Conda.
I solved it by changing the .condarc file to **solelely** include the following lines:

```
channels:
    - conda-forge
    - bioconda
    - defaults
```

The order is crucial as well.

Comment: Wait, what is version 1.9? Aren't you using version 1.16?

Comment: I know, I am pretty confused by that myself. I installed bcftools in a newly created conda env using ```conda install -c bioconda bcftools``` as indicated on https://anaconda.org/bioconda/bcftools and conda says v1.16

Comment: Conda might, but are you running the version installed in conda or the one on your system? Don't you need something like `conda run bcftools --version`?

Comment: I ran the following:
```conda activate bcftools1.16 ``` and then  ```conda list --show-channel-urls```.

Just to check again the version of bcftools: 

```# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel```
```bcftools                  1.9                  h68d8f2e_9    bioconda```

Comment: Please put all of this into the question. I don't know much about conda, but it still looks like you're running the system-wide one. What's the output of `type -a bcftools` and, `type -a bcftools | grep -v aliased | grep -oP '/\S+' | while read c; do echo "=== $c ==="; $c --version; done`?

Comment: I solved it, I added my solution to the question.

Comment: Great! But please post your solution as an answer instead so the question can be marked as slved.

Comment: Thank you for doing it for me. Very new to stackoverflow as you might have guessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that not installing the most recent version of Conda.
It was solved by changing the .condarc file to **solely** include the following lines:

```
channels:
    - conda-forge
    - bioconda
    - defaults
```

The order is crucial as well.

*Converted to answer from question.*